# Fade the background-color of a span tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fade, background-color, html

I'm trying to fade the background-color of a span tag using JQuery to emphasize when a change has occured.  I was thinking the code would be someting like the following inside the click handler, but I can't seem to get it working.  Can you show me where I went wrong?
Thanks Russ.

```
$("span").fadeOut("slow").css("background-color").val("FFFF99");
```

---

That's better, but now it fades both the background-color of the span tag and the text value of the span tag too.  I'm trying to just fade the background-color and leave the text visible.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OH, I didn't realize you wanted to fade the color! OK, so you need to check out the jQuery color plugin:

<s>http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color</s>

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

And here's another helpful section of the jQuery docs site:

http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations

I've never actually done this so I won't try to give you code, but I imagine the color plugin will give you the functionality you need.

Answer (score 16):

It can be done with the [color animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).  You'd then do something like

```
$('span').animate({'backgroundColor' : '#ffff99'});
```

Comment: If you already have jQuery UI, you're ready to animate color. `Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 10):

If using pure jQ to fade out a background doesn't work without a plugin, there's a clever (although not progressively enhanced) way to do this with CSS3.

This function will apply the "transition" attribute to a given element via CSS
Next, the element is given a background color which CSS fades into.

In case you want this to be like a wave ("look here!"), after a delay of half a second, a function is queued to turn the element back to white.

Essentially jQ just blinks the element on to one color, then back to white. CSS3 takes care of the fading.

```
//reusable function to make fading colored hints
function fadeHint(divId,color) {
    switch(color) {
        case "green":
        color = "#17A255";
        break;

        case "blue":
        color = "#1DA4ED";
        break;

        default: //if "grey" or some misspelled name (error safe).
        color = "#ACACAC";
        break;
    }

    //(This example comes from a project which used three main site colors: 
    //Green, Blue, and Grey)

    $(divId).css("-webkit-transition","all 0.6s ease")
    .css("backgroundColor","white")
    .css("-moz-transition","all 0.6s ease")
    .css("-o-transition","all 0.6s ease")
    .css("-ms-transition","all 0.6s ease")
    /* Avoiding having to use a jQ plugin. */

    .css("backgroundColor",color).delay(200).queue(function() {
        $(this).css("backgroundColor","white"); 
        $(this).dequeue(); //Prevents box from holding color with no fadeOut on second click.
    }); 
    //three distinct colors of green, grey, and blue will be set here.
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Saved me from more JS bloat.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with jQuery (or any lib) & a simple CSS hack:

```
#wrapping-div {
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}
#fadeout-div {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-color: #ffd700;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-1
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapping-div">
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <div id="fadeout-div"></div>
</div>
```

Then, all you need to do is:

```
$("#fadeout-div").fadeOut(1100);
```

Easy Peasy!  See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/jcSYp/

Comment: Thought of the same. Its a good option if you just need this effect. It will save you the cost of adding a whole new plugin to your site.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"green"},  100);
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"white" },  1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

May be late to answer, but a straight solution to your answer.

```
 $('span').css('background-color','#<from color>').animate({backgroundColor: '#<to color>'},{duration:4000});
```

Simple. No need of jqueryUI plugin, 3rd party tools and all.

Answer (score 3):

I didnt want to use a plugin
So to fade a background in and out i included this for the div class thats to have its background faded

```
.div-to-fade {
    -webkit-transition:background 1s;
    -moz-transition:background 1s;
    -o-transition:background 1s;
    transition:background 1s
}
```

the jquery which is in a button click

```
$('.div-to-fade').css('background', 'rgb(70, 70, 70)');
setTimeout(function(){$('.div-to-fade').css('background', '')}, 1000);
```

This will color the background light grey and then fade back to the orig color
I hope this contributes

Answer (score 1):

that's why you call fadeOut on the span tag. to get background fade animation you should use:

```
$('span').animate({'backgroundColor' : '#ffff99'});
```

as pointed by mishac. another way could be something like this:

```
$("span").fadeTo(0.5,"slow", function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFF99");
  $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

the above code will fadeout to 50% the entire span tag, then changes background and fadeIn. it isn't what you were looking for, but creates a decet animation without depending from other jquery plugins ;)

Answer (score 1):

The newest jQuery UI business allows you to do background-color transforms on most objects.
See here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

As for the guy asking about making a background transparent on roll-over to reveal an image would it not be simpler to build it like a normal jQuery image roll-over like the ones people use to switch nav images?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use this syntax:

```
$("span").fadeOut("slow").css("background-color", "#FFFF99");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it for my list with a hover:

CSS:

```
ul {background-color:#f3f3f3;}
li:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').on('touchstart', function () { $(this).css('background-color', ''); });
    $('li').on('touchend', function () { $(this).css('background-color', 'inherit'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution **without** jQuery UI https://stackoverflow.com/a/22590958/781695

```
//Color row background in HSL space (easier to manipulate fading)
$('span').css('backgroundColor','hsl(0,100%,50%');

var d = 1000;
for(var i=50; i<=100; i=i+0.1){ //i represents the lightness
    d  += 10;
    (function(ii,dd){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('span').css('backgroundColor','hsl(0,100%,'+ii+'%)'); 
        }, dd);    
    })(i,d);
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5NB3s/3/