# Pulsate the font size using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there a way to make [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons pulsate? (go big and little continuously)

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12776650/474597 and change font size instead of opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery.pulse.js](http://jsoverson.github.com/jquery.pulse.js/)

```
$('#target').pulse({fontSize: "24px"}, {duration : 100, pulses : -1});
```