# Javascript hide and show a div in a loop for a text "blink" effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently wanted to make a

element in a div with the ID of "test" to have a "blink" effect like most text editors have where the cursor is hidden and then shown, then hidden and shown....(in a loop) I tried to recreate this effect but just couldn't get it to work. Please help!

Here is some code:

`<div id="test">
    <p> _ </p>
    </div>`

Comment: How about the `<blink>` tag ?

Comment: `<blink>` is deprecated :( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink and browser support is very poor

Comment: How about posting some of your js code?

Comment: @ChrisB - It was a joke, and even the [wikipedia page for the blink tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element) has a javascript solution, so this should be easy to figure out.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205445/jquery-blinking-highlight-effect-on-div it will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
setInterval(function(){
     $("#test p").toggle();
},3000);
```

blinks every 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post! it worked!! (I'm a little new to web programming)

Comment: glad it helped! If this answer satisfies, mark it as accepted and close the thread, thanks!

Comment: Note: This will also remove any sizing that the `<p>` tag provides, because it uses the `display` style.  If you want the layout to remain, but the visibility to go on and off, you want to use something that alters the `visibility` style.

Comment: True, in that case you can do, `setInterval(function(){ if ( $('#test p').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('#test p').css('visibility','visible');
  else
    $('#test p').css('visibility','hidden'); },3000);`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concise, pure JavaScript way.

```
blink = setInterval(function () {
  element = document.querySelector("#test p");
  element.style.opacity = (element.style.opacity == 1 ? 0 : 1);
}, 500);
```

If you want to stop it, run `clearInterval(blink)`.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/UTIfapi/2/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example using Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/C58df/3/)

```
setInterval(function(){
    var elem = document.querySelector("#test p");
    if(isVisible(elem)) {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
},500);

function isVisible(elem) {
  return elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0;
}
```

(Though [knouroozi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055680/javascript-hide-and-show-a-div-in-a-loop-for-a-text-blink-effect/21055736#21055736) will stop the contents from shifting around, so I'd suggest that.)

[With JQuery it becomes simpler:](http://jsfiddle.net/C58df/2/)

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#test p').toggle();
},500);
```

([stckrboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21055790/573634) covers toggling visibility, rather than 'display', which will prevent the content from shifting around.)

Comment: You're welcome. You had the more elegant JS solution :)

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T6zQw/2/)

```
setInterval(function(){
     $("#test p").toggle();
},300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using jQuery and setInterval

```
$(".crsr").each(function(){
    var elem=$(this);
    setInterval( function() {
        if(elem.css('visibility')=='hidden') {
            elem.css('visibility','visible')
        } else {
            elem.css('visibility','hidden')
        }
    },500)
});
```

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBvkr/)

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my approach into the ring.   :)   Set up a class that changes the `visibility` to `hidden` and then use `setInterval` and `toggleClass` to toggle the class off and on.

**HTML**

```
<div id="blinkingText">
    Blink for me!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .blinkOn {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#blinkingText").toggleClass("blinkOn");
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```