# Jquery fade background / animate background colour on table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table

After much google searching and looking through other posts here i still can't work out if this is yet possible. I want to basically have a set background colour on my table rows that fades to another color quickly on :hover - Is this possible with Jquery?

I'm using multiple tables which will have, or would like to have, different colors for background hover, at the moment I'm using just CSS to do an hover event but obviously i want to try add a subtle but nice effect as they are nice chunky table rows.

****EDIT****

I found a solution: I am using Jquery UI -

```
$('tr').mouseover(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "#666" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It is possible by adding a class/style attribute to parent `tr` when you hover on its child td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would like to have different colors for background hover event for your table cells, this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBtFz/) shows you how to use the background color property to change the colors of each cell on mouse hover via a **Pseudo Color Map of NTSC Colors**.

There's no **jQuery** or other library required since this **pure CSS solution** keeps up with the users mouse position quickly.

I think using **animated fade** in the example I provided would make too many cells **linger with transitions** causing confusion. That said, it's still easy to add in jQuery animate effects if needed, but depends on your table layout scheme.

Here's a revised [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBtFz/1/) using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks i really like this approach

Comment: Thank you. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBtFz/4/) shows how to use the jQuery selector 1 time only, because all your doing is appending via query **.mouseout** to **.mouseover**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI's [Color Animate effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I am using Jquery UI -

```
$('tr').mouseover(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function() {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
        ({ backgroundColor: "#666" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The revised jsFiddle I provided for you two days ago is using jQuery UI. It's loaded as an asset on the left side. Also, my jQuery markup is using a variable for the time duration which is set at the top of the function. Isn't my answer the solution you found helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i used in one of my project.

```
     $('#table1 td, #table2 td').hover(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('active').animate({opacity: 0.65,}, 500);
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('active').animate(
             {opacity: 0.65,}, 500, function() {
           //Animation complete.
           $(this).animate({opacity: 1,}, 'slow');
     });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
```

And in your `css`, you should have something like:

```
#table1 .active { background: #CCC;}
#table2 .active { background: #F2F2F2;}
```

Comment: But this would not achieve a fade effect?

Comment: Updated the answer with simple opacity effect but this might not be want you want. If you're looking for a nice fade background effect you need to use a plugin for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734068/fade-the-background-color-of-a-span-tag-with-jquery