# How to Have the Hover Color Fade In and Out? - jQuery, HTML

Tags: jquery, html

## An Example:

Here is an HTML example I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgjnp/2/

## The Question:

### The CSS:

```
a {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;            
}

.green {
    color: green;                        
}
```

By the example, the set `class` is to get the `fade animation`, so the specified color fades in and out on `mouse hover`. Other than that, it should ***revert*** back to its default color.

The question is, how to have the hover color fade in and out?

Comment: If you're okay with using the jquery UI library, then check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734068/fade-the-background-color-of-a-span-tag-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate colors with plain jQuery. For that you have to use some sort of plugins, i.e. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) ( which is HUGE ) or the [Color animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

Alternatively you can use some simple CSS3 transitions - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgjnp/7/)

This works awesome in newer browsers but not in older IE-s.

```css
a {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-transition: color .5s linear;   
       -moz-transition: color .5s linear; 
            transition: color .5s linear;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great explanation [here](http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/). It doesn't use any fancy CSS3 magic, only JQuery. Just add the end and start colors, and JQuery will animate the transition.